# How to run ansible playbook on a remote windows machine as administrator and have the log output

Tags: linux, powershell, github, centos, ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Install winlogbeat
  hosts: windows
  tasks:
    - name: run winlogbeatinstall
      win_shell: |
        ((New-Object Net.WebClient -Property @{Proxy = [Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()}).DownloadFile('https://github/install.ps1','C:\ABCD\winlogbeatinstall.ps1'))
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-File C:\ABCD\winlogbeatinstall.ps1"
      register: out
    - debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

If I run these commands on the remote machine NOT as administrator it works.
If I run it from the playbook with the same NOT administrator domain user, only the download file works (1st command), the installing (2nd command) doesn't.
How can I make it work?

2nd question, when it runs as admin it opens a subshell and close it, so I don't have any output. Is it possible to somehow see the output?

Any suggestion is welcome how can I make this work?

Comment: Is your repo hosted on github (nothing internal)?  I don't advise creating a webclient to do the download, a simple `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri -OutFile` is better.  If your file does not have logging and does not output to stdout (for example, it's using `Write-Host`), then you can't capture its output.  Doesn't ansible run as system making `Start-Process` unnecessary?

Comment: My script has output: Filebeat is running and the config is good. I use the webclient because of the proxy settings.